# AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Tags: python, macos, jupyter, python-3.7

When I open my jupyter notebook I get errors.

I use google for help, but I can't find an answer.

I'm on macOS mojave and using python 3.7.2.I reinstalled my Jupiter notebook but no change.

When I input jupyter notebook. It show me these

```
Last login: Wed Apr 24 23:06:17
miracleleon@MiracledeMBP  ~  jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/init.py", line 25, in 
from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 610, in 
from .extensions import (
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/extensions.py", line 8, in 
from tornado.log import LogFormatter
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/log.py", line 34, in 
from tornado.escape import _unicode
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 27, in 
from tornado.util import unicode_type
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/util.py", line 18, in 
import typing
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 1356, in 
class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 1004, in new
self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

Answer (score 140):

Try uninstalling typing:

```
pip uninstall typing
```

or downgrading python to 3.6. There seems to be a problem with typing in 3.7

If after that you get:

> AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute '_ClassVar'

try `pip uninstall dataclasses`.

For more info refer to:
https://github.com/RTIInternational/gobbli/issues/10

Comment: When using Pip version 20.1 (released 29/04/2020), the solution of uninstalling the `typing` package no longer works for some reason. An easy workaround is to ensure you're using the previous version of Pip, 20.0.2, where this solution still works.

Comment: The `typing` package is only relevant on Python <= 3.5. Later versions include the `typing` module built-in, so you should uninstall it anyway.

Comment: You da real MVP @WhyNotHugo. I'm, using python 3.8 and apparently, some package like pandas or scrapy still lists typing as requirement and installing everything from pipfile fails. so the solution was to generate pipenv.lock file and just remove typing from it.

Comment: same error occurred in python 3.8.5, typing version 3.7.4.3.  Uninstall typing fixed my problem.

Comment: I've run into this with 3.8 as well but could not get pip to run uninstall.  I had to change directory into my site-packages directory and rm -rf typing* to manually uninstall it. 
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages is where mine is.

Comment: `typing` was very relevant for `Python 3.8.6`

Comment: One possible solution could be to delete venv folder since typing is also installed there.

Comment: @Jordan **what do you mean by** "no longer works"? Did it fail to uninstall `typing`? Or did it successfully uninstall `typing`, but Jupyter is still broken? Or just what exactly?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have the same problem and when I attempt to pip uninstall it, error that the OP mentions gets invoked when attempting to uninstall and prevents the uninstall.

Comment: For me, this bug is critical since it's breaking miniconda3

Comment: @WhyNotHugo you are an absolute legend