# Execute home assistant test cases using tox not working

Tags: python, python-3.7, tox, home-assistant

I have installed python3.7 on my ubuntu18.04 and trying to run home assistant test cases , The installation of python and all dependencies was successfully,

So upon installing python3.7, It internally install various packages for development and test python code. one of the package is `typing` which is internally installed. (typing is added as default since python 3.5)

On executing these test cases I am facing an error.

```
File "/home/phil/repos/core/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing.py", line 1357, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/phil/repos/core/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing.py", line 1005, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/phil/repos/core/.tox/py38/bin/python /home/phil/repos/core/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-pqbbs22j/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

#### One solution provided on [SO question 55833509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833509/attributeerror-type-object-callable-has-no-attribute-abc-registry) is `pip uninstall typing`, which is also not working.

1. Is there a way I can uninstall this default `typing` package as well?
2. Can we prevent install this `typing` package?
3. #### Any Other solution to fix this issue?

Comment: @mariusz, No .. sadly we chose not to continue with home-assistant ... If you find the solution kindly post and help others.

Answer (score 1):

`tox` is run in a virtual environment. Thus, removing `typing` will not help.

I assume that you `script/setup` after you cloned the repos and you have the system's [dependencies](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/development_testing) installed.

`tox -r` would rebuild the environment then.

Comment: thanks for help but I already did that, still facing same issue