# pyinstaller refusing to genrate .exe due to dataclasses

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-dataclasses

I'm using dataclasses, everything works alright in debug but when generating .exe with pyinstaller, I always have a recursion error. I tried to uninstall pyinstaller and reinstall the latest version.

Now pyinstaller is refusing to be installed:

> attributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'.

Does anyone have the same issue ?

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: to reinstall pyinstaller i'am using pip

Comment: I mean command to generate the exe

Comment: pyinstaller  --onedir --name myapp myapp.py

Comment: What python and pip version are you using?

Comment: Please try to uninstall dataclasses and then install pyinstaller. It seems that somehow dataclasses intervene with pickling as u can see [here](https://github.com/RTIInternational/gobbli/issues/10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833509/attributeerror-type-object-callable-has-no-attribute-abc-registry). Then reinstall an retry. Please let me know if it worked

Comment: It worked I upgraded python to 3.8 and reinstalled all the packages, generates the .exe with no problems :) Thank you !

Comment: I will write a solution for future reference from the community. Please accept if it worked for u or just write your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `dataclasses`
Then install `pyinstaller`
Then reinstall `dataclasses`

It seems that somehow `dataclasses` intervene with pickling as u can see [here](https://github.com/RTIInternational/gobbli/issues/10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833509/attributeerror-type-object-callable-has-no-attribute-abc-registry).
The same happens with the package named `typing`

As s_simmou mentioned, it might be necessary to upgrade to python 3.8 or later

Comment: Uninstalled dataclasses, then reinstalled; also did same for typing, but that's not the solution.

Comment: @Igor Micev are you using pandas

Comment: Yes, I'm using pandas. However, my problem is occurring on work with classes and inheritance and not related to pandas.

Comment: this is an answer to the question, how to reinstall pyinstaller. it is not for solving issues during the exe creation. anyway probably your problem has nothing to do with pandas, however pandas latest version doesn't work well with pyinstaller. I always had to downgrade pandas in the past before creating the exe. it might be related in the end. i mentioned just because is a common issue