# Can´t use pip or conda, getting: AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry' after install cityscapesscripts

Tags: python, linux, pip, conda

I installed mmdetection according to the installation instructions. Now I want to use the Cityscapes dataset and train the model. The installation of the MMdetector worked and the demo also ran. When I wanted to install the Cityscapesscript, the following warning message came up.

---

```
$ python -m pip install cityscapesscripts
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_auth-1.35.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib-3.4.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/protobuf-3.19.4-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_applehelp-1.0.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_devhelp-1.0.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_htmlhelp-2.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_jsmath-1.0.1-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_qthelp-1.0.3-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_serializinghtml-1.1.5-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_websupport-1.2.4-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zope.event-4.5.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zope.interface-5.4.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import abc
    File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
      from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
      class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
    File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
      self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
  AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Remainder of file ignored
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import abc
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/abc.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
  File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
    class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
  File "/home/8b90/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
    self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

---

Since then, neither pip nor conda has worked. I get the error message and don't know how to solve the problem.

I tried the following:

[AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833509/attributeerror-type-object-callable-has-no-attribute-abc-registry)

https://pypi.org/project/cityscapesScripts/

Here is the link to the Git repository: https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection

I would be happy to get an answer

Comment: didn't test youe stuff, but started getting such error when upgraded pip to the latest version... I just reinstalled python to use the initial pip & everything gets ok... perhaps, your mmdetector (or any) could  have done --upgrade pip (in a `quiet` mode) when being installed ?

Comment: "I tried the following:" - the problem you describe is exactly as in the first link (now the linked duplicate), and the problem is straightforwardly caused and fixed as described there. **What do you mean by** "I tried" that link? **What happened** when you tried that link, and **how does that not solve the problem**?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. I found where my Python packages are installed and manually deleted the typing module (I think it's called `typing.py`) file. The typing module, as far as I know, is now built into python from 3.7+, and causes problems when double-installed. This fixed pip for me.