# Azure WebApp Use Pipfile.lock instead of requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, azure

I am attempting to deploy a django web-app to an Azure web server. According to the documentation, for dependencies, it automatically looks for either a `requirements.txt` or a `setup.py`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#could-not-find-setuppy-or-requirementstxt).

Due to a bug in one of the sub dependencies of one of the packages, I cannot use a `requirements.txt` (See the 3rd comment of the answer of the following: [AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833509/attributeerror-type-object-callable-has-no-attribute-abc-registry)).

And instead, I must use a `Pipfile.lock` file instead. Just wondering how to actually use this in the install step. I am presuming I have to use the only other option which is a `setup.py` file, but I'm not sure what this file would look like. All the documentation I have seen online doesn't involve running a Pipfile in the setup.py script.

Any help is appreciated~

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a Django web app to Azure using a Pipfile.lock instead of a requirements.txt, modify the setup.py file to read the Pipfile.lock and extract the dependencies, then use the extracted dependencies in the install_requires argument of the setup() function. This allows Azure to install the specified dependencies during deployment.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do this? I am new to writing setup.py files and haven't found anything similar online

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQwj_wEA

Comment: in your script, what is "packages=['your_app']" meant to specify? Would that be the default root directory generated by Django?

Answer (score 0):

In my Django app, I generated piplock file by using the method below:-

```py
pip install pipenv
pipenv lock
```

[image]

My Pipfile.lock:-

```py
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "xxxx76effee8c7b80e4681e9321520166449ce8999a4ad0c168efdd"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.9"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "asgiref": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:xxxxa16eef663bc0e2e703ec6468e2fa8a5cd61cd449786d4f6e",
                "sha256:xxxxxxb45120216b23878cf6e8525eb3848653452b4192b92afed"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.7'",
            "version": "==3.7.2"
        },
        "django": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:xxxx3d6df1b141b1481e193b033fd1fdbda3ff52677dc81afdaacbaed",
                "sha256:xxxxc5a3da5a8d5b35cc6168f31b605971441798dac845f17ca8028039"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==4.2.3"
        },
        "sqlparse": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:xxxxd0f93e66f1efc6e1338a41884b7ddf2a350cedd20ccc4d9d28f3",
                "sha256:xxxxxb8349fa3061f0fe7f06ca94ba65b426946ffebe6e3e8295332420c"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.5'",
            "version": "==0.4.4"
        },
        "typing-extensions": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:xxxxxxx0174bf433bccd69b0babc3b15b1a8dca43789fd7f61514b36",
                "sha256:xxxx5db7ba217daeb99701ad295353c45f9e95963337ceeeffb2"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version < '3.11'",
            "version": "==4.7.1"
        },
        "tzdata": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:xxxxx95bdb1be05da659673de4acbd21bf9c69e94cc5e907a3a",
                "sha256:xxxxx099b6939b5546db7adce1e7d6f2e179e3df563c70511eda"
            ],
            "markers": "sys_platform == 'win32'",
            "version": "==2023.3"
        },
        "whitenoise": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:xxxxccaebxxx48450b8f0307ca368195a8",
                "sha256:xxxx9031cc9bb2cdbc8e5e53365407acf99f7ade9ec"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==6.5.0"
        }
    },
    "develop": {}
}
```

Now create a setup.py file like below and run it:-

**setup.py file:-**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='pycode',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'asgiref==3.7.2',
        'django==4.2.3',
        'sqlparse==0.4.4',
        'typing-extensions==4.7.1',
        'tzdata==2023.3',
        'whitenoise==6.5.0'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'pycode=pycode.cli:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

And install the setup.py file by running the command below:-

```py
python setup.py install
```

[image]

Comment: When pushing to Azure like I am, this throws the error "error in  setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing 
valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "'{'": Expected W:(0-9A-Za-z)"

Comment: Check my updated setup.py