# AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'Literal'

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, werkzeug

I have python 3.9 installed in my windows machine with a flask script working as expected. Then I tried to replicate the environment on my linux machine. I have the same python version and the exact same *pip list*. But in the linux machine I receive this error from mod_wsgi:

```
from flask import Flask, abort
File "/var/www/VirtualEnvs/newEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from . import json as json
File "/var/www/VirtualEnvs/newEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from ..globals import current_app
File "/var/www/VirtualEnvs/newEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 6, in <module>
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
File "/var/www/VirtualEnvs/newEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .serving import run_simple as run_simple
File "/var/www/VirtualEnvs/newEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 76, in <module>
t.Union["ssl.SSLContext", t.Tuple[str, t.Optional[str]], t.Literal["adhoc"]]
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'Literal'
```

I even tried upgrading to python3.10 and I have the same result:

```
from flask import Flask, abort
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from . import json as json
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from ..globals import current_app
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 6, in <module>
from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .serving import run_simple as run_simple
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 76, in <module>
t.Union["ssl.SSLContext", t.Tuple[str, t.Optional[str]], t.Literal["adhoc"]]
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'Literal'
```

My last idea was to *pip install --upgrade typing* which gave me this new error:

```
from flask import Flask, abort
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
import typing as t
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

As far as I know, this *pip install --upgrade typing* should not be used in this python version. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833509/attributeerror-type-object-callable-has-no-attribute-abc-registry) more details could be found.

Flask version 3.0.2
Werkzeug version 3.0.1

Comment: Do you happen to have a `typing.py` file in your working directory…?

Comment: I don't have it. Neither on my script directory or my /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ directory

Comment: Did you check the comment to the thread that you linked that said: `The typing package is only relevant on Python <= 3.5. Later versions include the typing module built-in, so you should uninstall it anyway`

Comment: Yes, installing it was just a last try. I uninstalled it after I saw the liked thread

Comment: Try `python3 -c 'import typing; print(typing)'` (or whatever your correct `python` executable is). What do you get?

Comment: I receive <module 'typing' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/typing.py'> (for my python3.9 env). <module 'typing' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py'> (for my python 3.10 env)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. My mod-wsgi was compiled against python3.7. So any virtualenv with different python version won't work.

I solved it by downloading last mod-wsgi version and compiling it against the same python3.9 as my virtualenv (./configure --with-python=/path/to/python)

Comment: Hi galex, welcome to SO. While your link may solve the question, answers that heavily rely on links are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained. Thanks